# Count pages on tiff raises TypeError: int() argument must be a string

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am working on some images with tiff extension and I have a step that I should count the pages of each tiff image
Here's my try till now

```
from pathlib import Path
from PIL import Image
import os

def count_pages(img):
    i = 0                                                                           
    while True:
        try:   
            img.seek(i)
        except EOFError:
            break       
        i += 1          
    return i

BASE_DIR = Path.cwd()
IDs_DIR = BASE_DIR / 'FLDR'
sPath = os.path.join(IDs_DIR, 'ggg.tiff')    
im = Image.open(sPath)
print(count_pages(im))
```

But with some of the tiff (not all of them), I encountered an error like that

```
site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py:845: UserWarning: Corrupt EXIF data.  Expecting to read 2 bytes but only got 0.
  warnings.warn(str(msg))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Demo.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(count_pages(im))
  File "Demo.py", line 9, in count_pages
    img.seek(i)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1101, in seek
    self._seek(frame)
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1142, in _seek
    self._setup()
  File "C:\Users\Future\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\PIL\TiffImagePlugin.py", line 1333, in _setup
    xsize = int(self.tag_v2.get(IMAGEWIDTH))
TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

Comment: you are passing NoneType to  `int()`

Comment: How can I fix that, please?

Answer (score 0):

As the UserWarning suggests, some of your TIFF images are corrupted. This is what's causing the exception when you attempt to seek to the start of the image - because PIL is unable to get the image width from the EXIF metadata.

If you are able to, the simplest solution is to run the corrupted images through a tool such as FFmpeg as an attempt to regenerate and repair them.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you post a link that shows how to use FFmpeg tool or how to fix the corrupted images?

Comment: Another question: how can I skip such images?

Comment: The same way that you'd "skip" anything else that causes an exception to be raised (taking on the full risk that doing so causes something else to break further down the line): handle the exception with `try`/`except`.